# Найти количество повторяющихся подряд символов в строке через запрос SQL

Tags: sql

Необходимо создать запрос в MS SQL, который будет выводить в колонку (Count) количество повторяющихся подряд символов (в моем случае цифр) из колонки (String) таблицы. Можно ли это сделать без использования внешних функций? Пример результата:

| String | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 12344444567 | 5 |
| 9584028176 | 1 |
| 99 | 2 |

Для обработки нулей использовал следующий код:

```
select String, case
                when (cast(String as decimal(28,0)) <> 0 and ((cast(cast(String as numeric(28,2))as bigint))%1000000000) = 0) then 9
                when (cast(String as decimal(28,0)) <> 0 and ((cast(cast(String as numeric(28,2))as bigint))%100000000) = 0) then 8
                when (cast(String as decimal(28,0)) <> 0 and ((cast(cast(String as numeric(28,2))as bigint))%10000000) = 0) then 7
                when (cast(String as decimal(28,0)) <> 0 and ((cast(cast(String as numeric(28,2))as bigint))%1000000) = 0) then 6
                when (cast(String as decimal(28,0)) <> 0 and ((cast(cast(String as numeric(28,2))as bigint))%100000) = 0) then 5
                when (cast(String as decimal(28,0)) <> 0 and ((cast(cast(String as numeric(28,2))as bigint))%10000) = 0) then 4
                when (cast(String as decimal(28,0)) <> 0 and ((cast(cast(String as numeric(28,2))as bigint))%1000) = 0) then 3
                when (cast(String as decimal(28,0)) <> 0 and ((cast(cast(String as numeric(28,2))as bigint))%100) = 0) then 2
 end Count
from Table p
```

Обработать остальные цифры затрудняюсь.

Comment: А почему во второй строке ответа количество ноль, а не один?

Comment: Правильнее будет 1, верно, просто мне важно кол-во дубликатов, а если их <2 то не важно что там.

Comment: Поскольку неизвестны ни местоположение повторяющихся символов, ни то, какой это символ, а сами значения, в которых надо искать, достаточно короткие, считаю наиболее быстрым решением рекурсивный CTE, который убирает по одному символу, например с конца, а также тащит за собой счётчик, который инкрементится, если последний и предпоследний символы совпадают, либо сбрасывается, а также тащится поле текущего максимума счётчика.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, как пример разборки-подчстета символов

```
with nn as(select 1 i union all select i+1 from nn where i<20) -- серия чисел от 1 до..
-- исходные данные
,data as(select * from ( values
 (1,'12344455')
,(2,'123333433355aaaAA')
  )t(id,sv)
  )
-- разборка строки на символы
,syms as(
select id,i,substring(sv,i,1)s1 
  ,sv
from data d
inner join nn on i<=len(sv)
)
-- проставим признак текущий символ отличается от предыдущего - начало группы
,grs as(
select *
  ,case when s1<>lag(s1,1,'')over(partition by id order by i) then 1 else 0 end ns
from syms
)
-- пронумеруем группы последовательностей
,grn as(
select *
  ,sum(ns)over(partition by id order by i) grn
from grs
)
-- подсчитаем число символов каждой группе
,seq as(
select id,min(s1)s1,count(*)q,min(i) i
from grn
group by id,grn
)
select * 
from seq
order by id,i
;
```

Результат разборки-группировки

| id | s1 | q | i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 8 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 11 |
| 2 | a | 5 | 13 |